# Update text inside contenteditable as user is typing

Tags: javascript

How can the content of my contenteditable element be lively updated without having my content mirrored?

Desired result: `<p>Hello</p>`

Current result: `<p>olleH</p>`

```js
const editor = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(editor);
editor.addEventListener("keyup", handleChange, false);
editor.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
editor.setAttribute(
  "style",
  "background-color: lightgrey; height:50vh; width: 100vw"
);

function handleChange() {
  editor.innerHTML = `<p>${editor.textContent}</p>`
}
```

Comment: a contentEditable should update itself, no need to catch changes.

Comment: I want to stylize it, typing in it would generate a div, I'd want it to be a p tag.

Comment: why not just make a <P contenteditable> then?

Comment: A simple parser, with the results in the "result" div: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-sutherland-jmdz9?file=/src/index.js:178-218 I'd like the "results" to be directly in the "editor" ps: refresh the preview for it to start working

Answer (score 0):

Change `<p>${editor.innerHTML}</p>` to `<p>${editor.textContent}</p>`

```js
const editor = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(editor);
editor.addEventListener("keyup", handleChange, false);
editor.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
editor.setAttribute(
  "style",
  "background-color: lightgrey; height:50vh; width: 100vw"
);

function handleChange() {

  editor.innerHTML = `<p>${editor.textContent}</p>`
}
```